# How to assign data from a file to a pointer in struct?

Tags: c, pointers

i would like to read some data from a file and assign it to the dynamic array which is a member of struct. Here's the struct:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int* dynamicArray;
}
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
```

There is a function from my programme. I'm trying to read the data from a file but something's going wrong. My code:

```
MyStruct* myfunction(const char* filename){
   FILE* inputFile;
   int someValue = 3;
   inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");
   MyStruct* obj = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
   obj->dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * someValue);
   int i = 0;
   for(i; i < someValue; i++)
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &obj->dynamicArray[i]);
   return obj;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: And _what_ goes wrong? Note: you don't check if `fopen` succeeded.

Comment: You also forget to close the file.

Comment: What exactly does *"I'm trying to read the data from a file but something's going wrong"* mean? How is your data formatted? Try checking the return value from `fscanf`.

Comment: What structure has file? Some like this: "1,2,3,4555,309,-222" OR "1 2 3 4 48495 -12039" In one line or many?

Comment: Well, sorry, maybe it was not really clear description. I meant that an array contains not proper int values - maybe some memory addressess, or totally random number, but for sure not these items that i store in a file.

Comment: I would not be sure about operator precedence here and would use more `()`.

Comment: Structure of a file: "3 5 99" - something like this

Comment: If `fopen()` is successful, I think your code should work.

Comment: How are you viewing / printing the array? I agree with @Barmar. Your code should work if that is truly your input.

Comment: as an example the second element of an array: printf("%d", *((*obj).dynamicArray+1));

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. We cannot guess what went wrong from your code snippets. The code you show in the question looks OK providing `fopen` succeeds, which you really need to check BTW.

Comment: Check that `fopen` returns a non-null `FILE *` and that `fscanf` returns 1 (the correct number of items).